# How are the locations of solar system planets expressed in their orbits?

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy, planets, solar-system, data

and where can I find the data about the locations of the solar system planets during their entire year?
I would like to find the data on the orbits of solar system plantes. Also I would like to know how can one express the location of each planet in their orbits? Can one for example use cartesian coordinates with center of the sun as the origin? or whta is the way scientists (astronomers, cosmologist, or astrophysicists) express the location of each of them?

Comment: Ask Wolfram: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=venus+location

Comment: There is a free and very powerful program called Stellarium which provides all that information and more. You can download it or use the web version. Click [here](http://stellarium.org).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something called an *ephemeris*, which is a catalogue of moon, planet, and star positions throughout the year.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: This is a big book that has the positions of all the planets and main stars printed in it for every minute of the day, every day of the year. By measuring those positions with a special telescope and looking up the numbers in the book for the exact time you have locally, you can pinpoint your position on the globe.

Answer (score 0):

Ephemeris or its plural ephemerides is the trajectory and position information and dynamics for planets, moons, satellites or other orbital bodies. A good place to find this info is at JPL Horizons at; https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi Hope this helps.